# How to run a method in an unblocking way in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, rabbitmq, nonblocking

I have a Java program where the program listens to incoming HTTP messages from RabbitMQ, and upon receiving a push notification, will do some processing.

```
channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                    byte[] body) throws IOException {
                // (process the message components here ...)
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                ProcessMessage(message);
            }
        });
```

Now my only concern is how to efficiently call the `ProcessMessage(message);` method. If it takes a long time, I am not sure if I'm being blocked from receiving new notifications.

What I had in mind was to simply run the method inside a new Thread inline. But I think that creates a new thread everytime. Even if I kill afterwards, this creation and killing might add overheads.

My questions are:

1. Am I being blocked right now from receiving new messages? (as long as I don't miss any messages, it is fine being queued somewhere)
2. I know `Executor` also does the job. But does `new Thread()` approach do the job?

Comment: You can create an `Executor` and submit a work item into it for each message you receive.

Comment: For further readings: [Oracle's tutorial on the `Executor` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)

Comment: Ummm, how does it differ from a `new Thread();` approach?

Comment: And most importantly, am I blocked here?

Comment: @TinaJ please take a look at the tutorial I provided. Among other things, it explains the difference between an `Executor` and a `Thread`.

Comment: Tnx. I will do that. Is that the easiest/simplest way?!

Comment: "Easy" and "simple" are opinion-based characteristics and thus off-topic to StackOverflow.

Comment: More generally: "easy" and "simple" are rarely attributes of concurrent systems. Even systems that make concurrency relatively easy and simple are generally leaky abstractions, and the underlying mechanism is often quite complex. If you're serious about this sort of thing, the *definitive* book is [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) by Goetz et al. The [sample chapter](http://jcip.net/jcip-sample.pdf) available on the JCIP site actually discusses why you should prefer to use an `Executor` rather than manually creating a `Thread`.

Comment: I suspect you already use the easiest/simplest way to handle messages, and no improvements needed.

Comment: @DanielPryden Can you post an answer for `Executor`? So you will get a credit, and I get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TinaJ: You already have an answer, in the linked duplicate. That's how duplicate questions work on Stack Overflow. And I don't need any more rep points in the Java tag. :-)

Comment: @DanielPryden I only see one answer there, that only based on Java 8. I'm on 1.7.

Comment: @TinaJ: There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2804722) in the other linked duplicate, although I admit it's not a great answer. I'll probably come back around and add a better answer there at some point when I have a minute.

Comment: @DanielPryden checked that already. No snippet inside. Yes, please do.